# Image Flipping in WPF

Tags: wpf, reflection, image

How do you get an image to be reflected in wpf without using the xaml? I have a rectangle with a BitmapImageBrush as its fill. I want to be able to regularly flip this image (X-axis) back and forth at will in C#. I've read about using the ScaleTransform property but this only seems to work in the xaml and that's not what I want.

This is how the image is created:

```
ImageBrush l = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(uriPath, UriKind.Relative)));
_animation.Add(l);

_visual = new Rectangle();
_visual.Fill = _animation[0];
_visual.Width = width;
_visual.Height = height;
_visual.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
_window.GameCanvas.Children.Add(_visual);
```

_animation is a list of ImageBrushes.
This is really simple, yet I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still add a scale transform programmatically, rather than using xaml.

For instance, [in this article.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/userinterface/article.php/c12221)

To do the flip, set your scale transform to be negative in the direction you want to flip (ie, if horizontal, set x to -1, or -desiredScale if you also want to resize).